# calculating co-relation of joint density function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I need to find the co-relation coefficient of the given joint density function of 
two random variables $X$ and $Y$:

$$   f(x,y) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{1}{210}(2x+y) & \quad 2<x<6, 0<y<5 \\
            0 & \quad otherwise
        \end{array}
    \right.      $$

What I have done so far is:

a) $E[X]$:  $$     \int_{2}^{6} x \frac{1}{210}(2x+y) dy         $$
b) $E[X^2]$:  $$     \int_{2}^{6} x^2 \frac{1}{210}(2x+y) dy         $$ 
c) $E[Y]$ :  $$     \int_{0}^{5} y \frac{1}{210}(2x+y) dy         $$ 
d) $E[Y^2]$ :  $$     \int_{0}^{5} y^2 \frac{1}{210}(2x+y) dy         $$
e) $Var[X]$: $$          E[X^2]-(E[X])^2                           $$ 
f) $Var[Y]$: $$          E[Y^2]-(E[Y])^2                           $$
g) $E[XY]$ :  $$     \int_{0}^{5}\int_{2}^{6} xy \frac{1}{210}(2x+y) dxdy$$

Is my method till here correct?

Comment: Keep in mind the [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) that says $$E(g(X,Y))=\iint g(x,y) f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

Comment: (a),(b),(c),(d) have a missing integral for $dx$; (g) is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps (a)-(d) are incorrect. Recall that $$\mathbb{E}[x] = \int x\,f_X(x)\,dx$$ over the appropriate region. In your steps, you are integrating the product of $x$ and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ (i.e.\ the **joint** distribution of $X$ and $Y$). You should first find the marginal distribution of X from the joint distribution by integrating over the appropriate range of $y$:
$$
f_X(x) = \int f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dy
$$
In this case, the integral would be

$$
f_X(x) = \int_0^5 \frac{1}{210} (2x + y)\,dy
$$
(note that the resulting expression for $f_X(x)$ is of course only valid for $2 < x < 6$ as suggested by the original domain).

Once you have the marginal distribution of $X$, you can find its expectation and variance. You'll want to do a similar process for $Y$.

Comment: Finding distributions is not necessary to find their moments. We have [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) theorem at hand. So OP's expression for (g) is correct.

Comment: You're right, I've edited the answer. Thanks!